# Error "functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1" code while installing Firebase

Tags: firebase, installation, error-handling

I am not really a developer - more of a hack job.  But I got to the very end of the install and getting this message.

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Here is the rest of the code errors:
ryanantrim@MacBook-Pro-2 node_modules % firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'virtusocial-fafe6'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/ryanantrim/Virtusocial/Assets/SocialAppTemplate/FirebaseCloudFunctions/FirebaseFunctions/functions
> eslint .

/Users/ryanantrim/Virtusocial/Assets/SocialAppTemplate/FirebaseCloudFunctions/FirebaseFunctions/functions/index.js
1:7  error  'functions' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ryanantrim/.npm/_logs/2021-01-08T00_43_37_222Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Answer (score 0):

I solved a very similar issue correcting all the errors specified by eslint.

To see them, use the command **nom run lint**.